# Is it possible to make authentication in identityserver4 only available via REST calls?

Tags: postman, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm quite new with identityserver4 so correct me if I say something wrong. I have set up identityserver4 together with ASP Identity for usermanagement and protected my API with it, however I don't know how to get an access token without having to be redirected to the login page. I'm using postman to get an access token via the authorization tab using the following details:

[image]

```
  new Client
  {
     ClientId = "postman-api",
     ClientName = "Postman Test Client",
     ClientSecrets = { new Secret("PostmanIsASecret".Sha256()) },
     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
     AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
     RequireConsent = false,
     RedirectUris = { "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"},
     PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://www.getpostman.com" },
     AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://www.getpostman.com" },
     EnableLocalLogin = false,
     RequirePkce = false,
     AllowedScopes =
     {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        "jumsum.api"
     }
}
```

I just want to login and get an access token without having to be redirected all the time. In the console I'm getting this:

```
IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator: Information: Showing login: User is not authenticated
```

I just want to pass a username and password via the http request body and get an access token back. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a client that accepts the **client credentials flow** and using this flow you can get an access token using just a username and password. This is a flow for machine-to-machine communication where no human user is involved.

Read more about that [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/client_authentication.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I actually meant to login with a username and password made via ASP.net Identity, but this is even better for postman testing. What I was looking for was ResourceOwnerPassword grant type, however I fount out that it's not the recommended way to go, so I'll stick with ClientCredentials for postman and other grant types for other clients. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: No problems, client credientals or the authorization code flow, is the only two you should use, all other flows are not recomended and deprectated. You can in postman login as a user (via redirect to your identity provider) https://www.wardvanbesien.info/post/oidc-with-postman/